# Top 5 scores from google leaderboard

Tags: android, google-api, andengine, google-play-games, leaderboard

My requirement is to get top 5 scores from leaderboard and display it in my app.

There is a method loadTopScores but it shows the scores in its own UI i guess.

```
mGamesClint.loadTopScores(new OnLeaderboardScoresLoadedListener() {

            public void onLeaderboardScoresLoaded(int arg0, LeaderboardBuffer arg1,
                    LeaderboardScoreBuffer arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub




            }
        }, LEADERBOARD_ID,LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME  , LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC, 5, true);
```

So is there any way I can get individual data like Name and score..?

Name 1 : Name of the top scorer 1
score 1 : score of the top scorer 1

Name 2 : Name of the top scorer 2
score 2 : score of the top scorer 2

......and so on

I just want name string and score integer so that I can use it in my game.

Please suggest me some ideas

Comment: can you please post your solution here? I am searching the same thing but I am not able to get a solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Solution which worked is as follows which is for the latest game play services.

```
  Games.Leaderboards.loadTopScores(mGamesClint,LEADERBOARD_ID, LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC, 5).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadScoresResult>() {

        public void onResult(LoadScoresResult arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int size = arg0.getScores().getCount();



            for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )  {

                LeaderboardScore lbs = arg0.getScores().get(i);

                String name = lbs.getScoreHolderDisplayName();

                String score = lbs.getDisplayScore();

                Uri urlimage = lbs.getScoreHolderHiResImageUri();

                 }

 }
```

you can get all the data from leaderboard users here including high resolution image ie. profile picture.
Hope you get the idea here.

Comment: looks fine but you should close the scorebuffer after you're done (according to the reference): arg0.getScores().close();

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track in your example, you just need to extract the information once it is loaded. It is fairly confusing to get it working but I will point you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23853222/1326821) of mine, which shows how to do it for achievements - doing it for leaderboards works the same way, except that you will use the leaderboard interfaces instead of those used for achievements.

Basically, you will access `arg2` to get the data, and it should look something like this:

```
mGamesClint.loadTopScores(new OnLeaderboardScoresLoadedListener() {

   public void onLeaderboardScoresLoaded(int arg0, LeaderboardBuffer arg1, LeaderboardScoreBuffer arg2) {

      // iterate through the list of returned scores for the leaderboard
      int size = arg2.getCount();
      for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )  {
         LeaderboardScore lbs = arg2.get( i );

         // access the leaderboard data
         int rank = i + 1;         // Rank/Position (#1..#2...#n)
         String name = lbs.getScoreHolderDisplayName();
         String scoreStr = lbs.getDisplayScore();
         long score = lbs.getRawScore();

         // now display or cache these values, or do whatever with them :)
      }

      arg2.close();
      arg1.close();
   }
}, LEADERBOARD_ID,LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC, 5, true);
```

I did not actually test this implementation, but it should work (or at least show you enough so you can fix any mistakes I might have made).

Just remember that this will be done asynchronously, so the contents of the method will not execute immediately, but rather once the scores have been loaded.

Comment: with this I can get score and names from leaderboard and create my own UI for leaderboard..

Comment: My pleasure, I'm glad to help. And since there were no examples I could find anywhere it is good to have it written down somewhere for future reference.

Comment: any chance you could post the working code? this doesn't seem to work as it is

Comment: @behelit I can't write your code for you, I can only point you in the right direction - this was never meant to be working code, just an example. Consult the documentation if you need further explanation.

Comment: I cant find OnLeaderboardScoresLoadedListener listener anywhere, I have searched the docs and every thing I can, Can you please help?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I have achieved it.

```
PendingResult<Leaderboards.LoadScoresResult> topScores = 
            Games.Leaderboards.loadTopScores(getApiClient(),LEADERBOARD_ID,LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC, 1, true);
            topScores.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadScoresResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onResult(LoadScoresResult scoreResults) {

                    if(scoreResults != null) {
                        if (scoreResults.getStatus().getStatusCode() == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
                            scoreStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                            LeaderboardScoreBuffer scoreBuffer = scoreResults.getScores();
                            Iterator<LeaderboardScore> it = scoreBuffer.iterator();
                            while(it.hasNext()){
                                 LeaderboardScore temp = it.next();
                                 Log.d("PlayGames", "player"+temp.getScoreHolderDisplayName()+" id:"+temp.getRawScore() + " Rank: "+temp.getRank());
                                 scoreStringBuilder.append("|"+temp.getScoreHolderDisplayName()+"*"+temp.getRawScore());
                            }
                            UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(handlerName, "onGetScoreSucceededEventListener", "");
                             Log.d("PlayGames", "Call Sent for getHighScorewithPlayerNameSuccess ::: "+handlerName);


                        }
                    }

                }});
```

You can use it as you want I created a String and returned it to Unity and then parsed it.
But this code is working with Latest Google Play Services.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This code gets you the top 5 scores on your leaderboard.

```
private LeaderboardsClient mLeaderboardsClient; 

    mLeaderboardsClient.loadTopScores("HgkF9bOSF_UPAAILKE", LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC,5,true).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AnnotatedData<LeaderboardsClient.LeaderboardScores>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(AnnotatedData<LeaderboardsClient.LeaderboardScores> leaderboardScoresAnnotatedData) {

                            LeaderboardScoreBuffer scoreBuffer = leaderboardScoresAnnotatedData.get().getScores();
                            Iterator<LeaderboardScore> it = scoreBuffer.iterator();
                            while(it.hasNext()){
                                LeaderboardScore temp = it.next();
                                Log.d("PlayGames", "player"+temp.getScoreHolderDisplayName()+" id:"+temp.getRawScore() + " Rank: "+temp.getRank());
                            }

                        }
                    });
```