# How can I get highscores from google play services leaderboard?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

My leaderbaord is working fine. The problem is whenever the game is updated, the highscore is getting back to zero in-game. The user's leaderboard is fine, it is showing the correct highscore, but not the in-game highscore. How can I get the highscore of the user from the leaderboard? So that I can update the highscore also whenever the game is updated. I'm using the google play services in Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057643/top-5-scores-from-google-leaderboard/24070729#24070729) which shows you how to obtain the leaderboard information.

A good way to ensure that the in-game high score remains synchronized with the online value is to do this at every sign-on.