# Show Custom Leaderboard UI

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I have managed to display the default `Google Play Services` leaderboard in `Unity3D`.

Is there a way to display a custom `UI` for the leaderboard in `Unity3D`? If yes, how?

Comment: It is possible to get the leaderboard information (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057643/top-5-scores-from-google-leaderboard/24070729#24070729)). Once you have that you can display it any way you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am not sure whether you want to know how to create the UI or the leaderboard (or both)?

If you mean the networking part (eg updating a leaderboard online), I would suggest doing it through something like PUN? LINK: https://www.exitgames.com/en/PUN